# Wait for scheduled task to complete

Tags: c#, winapi, scheduled-tasks

I need to run a `Scheduled Task` on a remote computer.

Now the problem is to wait for completion (I want to open a file created by that task afterwards).

Somehow `Task.IsActive` is not usable (value is never set).

So I came up with this approach, but sometimes this is not working correctly.

It seems like `Task.Run()` is called but the actual Task has not started yet and `task.GetInstances()` returns 0.

*This leads to `'FileNotFound'` afterwards since the task hasn't done anything yet.*

Any Idea on how I can make sure that task is started and executed before exiting this method?

In other words: **How do I wait for a scheduled task to complete ?**

```
private async Task<bool> RunRemoteTaskAsync(string computername, string taskname)
{
    try
    {
        Status = string.Empty;
        Cursor = Cursors.Wait;

        Status = $"Starting [ {taskname} ]";

        using (Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.TaskService service = new Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.TaskService(computername))
        {
            //Find Task:
            Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Task task = service.FindTask(taskname);
            if (task == null)
            {
                 Status = $"Task [{taskname}] not found.";
                 Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
                 return false;
            }
            task.Run();                                       

            //Show State on UI
            Status = $"Running task '{taskname}' on '{computername}'";

            //Wait for completion:
            Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.RunningTaskCollection instances = task.GetInstances();
            while (instances.Count == 1) <-- Sucks because if more then 1 Task is running I cannot tell if its the one I started inside of this method or any other random task...
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
                instances = task.GetInstances();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            Status = $"Task completed";
            Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Status = $"{taskname} fehlgeschlagen";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about your proposed solution. But what problem are you ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: well the question is **How do I wait for a sheduled task to complete** (the way microsoft expected us to do)

Comment: Again, this is asking about your solution. Why do you believe, that waiting for a scheduled task to run to completion is required? Why not simply ask about the **real** problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: But that is my problem. I am running a Task which is creating a file I need to open as soon as it's done...

Comment: But sometimes it's just 'skipping' the task and trying to open the file (which is not created yet) => this leads to the problem that the task is not awaited in a correct manner ... ergo => what is the correct manner/ what have I done wrong

Comment: So instead of waiting for the file to become available, you have decided to solve the somewhat unrelated problem of waiting for the producer to terminate? This is generally called *"code by coincidence"*, and the question falls into the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/205381) category.

Comment: imo this is only partly the case. Part of my problem is that `task.GetInstances()` returns 0 right after I started the task.

Comment: What about [using a semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: @WillyK. the problem is on the `Task` object of the `Win32.TaskScheduler` it's not a thread i start myself.